# if Yosef collected a 20 percent tax on the grain before the famine, what did Yosef later change about Egyptian taxation?

Tags: yosef, miketz, vayigash

In Genesis 41:34 Yosef advises Pharoah to collect 20% of the grain of the Egypt and store it while the famine has not yet arrived.

> יַעֲשֶׂ֣ה פַרְעֹ֔ה וְיַפְקֵ֥ד פְּקִדִ֖ים עַל⁠־הָאָ֑רֶץ וְחִמֵּשׁ֙ אֶת⁠־אֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרַ֔יִם בְּשֶׁ֖בַע שְׁנֵ֥י הַשָּׂבָֽע

Presumably this was collected as a tax, or was purchased with tax money. Otherwise, how did they obtain this grain? So we see that Pharaoh already had taxing power. (You could argue that the taxing power existed but was less than 20% and only subsequently became 20%, but that seems like a stretch to me.)

Yet in Genesis 47:24 Yosef states he has now acquired 20% tax power through selling grain to the people:

> וְהָיָה֙ בַּתְּבוּאֹ֔ת וּנְתַתֶּ֥ם חֲמִישִׁ֖ית לְפַרְעֹ֑ה וְאַרְבַּ֣ע
> הַיָּדֹ֡ת יִהְיֶ֣ה לָכֶם֩ לְזֶ֨רַע הַשָּׂדֶ֧ה וּֽלְאׇכְלְכֶ֛ם
> וְלַאֲשֶׁ֥ר בְּבָתֵּיכֶ֖ם וְלֶאֱכֹ֥ל לְטַפְּכֶֽם

What was this new power that he obtained for the Pharoah that he did not have before?

Answer (score 3):

According to the R Avraham ben HaRambam, Yosef indeed wasn't acquiring a new power for Pharaoh, but rather through letting the people live on the land he was making the existing 20% power sufficiently palatable to the people to keep doing it in perpetuity:

[וחמש – נאמרו בו שני פירושים אחד מהם שיטת המתרגם והמפרשים הנמשכים אחריו שהוא מטעם הזירוז נגזר מן וחמשים עלו וג׳ והשני שיטת אבי אבא ז״ל שהוא נגזר מן החומש [וסיוע לפירוש זה מה שאמר (יוסף) בסוף הסיפור בפרשת ויגש ונתתם חמישית לפרעה שהוא החומש] וטעמו שיוציאו את החומש מתבואת מושבי ארץ מצרים; ואמר (אבי אבא) ז״ל כי זה [או] שהיה מנהג קדום להם שהמלך יקח את החומש מן התבואות או מנהג שחידש (יוסף) והורה היתר לעצמו לחדש אותו לפי שזה קל על אנשי הארץ לרוב המענה בתבואת הארץ ומחירה הזול בשבע שני השבע ולפי שהם ירויחו בזה לעתיד כמו שבאמת הודו על זה בשעת הזריעה (ואמרו) החיתנו נמצא חן וג׳ ועשה זה (יוסף) ע״ה למנהג קבוע שהתחיל מן שבע שני השבע וחיזק אותו אחר שני הרעב וישם אותה לחוק; ופירוש שני זה עדיף לפי הנראה לי.](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/R._Avraham_b._HaRambam/Bereshit/41.34#m7e0n6)

Answer (score 0):

Rashi on 41:34 follows Onkelos, and explains וחמש this:

> כתרגומו 'ויזרז' וכן וחמושים (שמות יג, יח')
>
> As it is translated 'and he should hurry (others)' like וחמושים's translation (shemos 13:18)

Meaning, at first it wasn't (necessarily) a 20% tax. In fact, from the next passuk we see that Yosef suggested taking *all* the food (presumably whatever wasn't needed for the current year)

> ויקבצו את **כל** אוכל השנים הטובות הבאות האלה

So Yosef was actually limiting his tax to 20% (which, during a famine, might've been more than 'whatever wasn't needed for the current year').

In addition, the first tax was presumably only meant to be for the years of plenty, during which Yosef taxed them in order to save the food for the years of famine. Once the famine started, the tax might've reverted back to nothing, until the Egyptians sold their land.

Comment: It's stated that the right to tax 20% was compensation for letting the Egyptians have food. So it doesn't make sense to me to say that it was a limitation.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough @torahmike. I meant that the tax at first wasn't set. It was just whatever they had left over. Now, it was set at 20%, which in theory could end up being more than 'whatever they had left over'